# Creating Jquery Plugin with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

this is my first time creating plugin. But my plugin have some little issue. I have created a simple replica of my plugin below

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(url){
    return this.each(function() {
        element = $(this);
        $.getJSON(url, function(response){
            elem.val(response.init_value);
        });
    });
}
```

and Initiated Like this

```
$("#test1").myPlugin('/get1.json'); //this should value 1
$("#test2").myPlugin('/get2.json'); //this should value 2
```

but the result is not working as expected

```
Element #test1 has done nothing, no value (I think it is broken)
Element #test2 has value of 2
```

My plugin is working fine when i initiate a single instance but when im trying to make a multiple instances, only the last instance is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this occurs because you've declared `element` without using `var`.

This way you've declared `element` as a global variable, so `element = $(this);` is basically the same as `window.element = $(this);`. Because of this, the second function call will overwrite the first instance of `element`.

That should be a simple fix: `var element = $(this);`

Comment: OMG. that was it? thank you vi5ion! You save my day.